# Close fragment on API Response, when app is in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

How can i close a fragment when the app is in background and the API response arrives.

When the app is running,`fragmentActivity.onBackPressed()` does the work, but in case when app is in background, the fragment remains as it is when user resumes the app.

Comment: you want to close the fragment or restart the fragment or load the api again ?

Comment: I want to close the fragment when the response arrives. Suppose a situation where user is in CartFragment. He places his order and press the home key. When success response arrives, I want to take him to HomeFragment with message "Order Placed'. But since he has pressed home key, `fragmentActivity.onBackpressed()` is not fulfilling the task.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want HomeFragment to start when you receive success response? So is the app to restart automatically when you receive the response or you want the app to start at HomeFragment the next time the user launches the app?

Comment: @Anuraag I want the app to start at HomeFragment the next time the user launches the app.

Comment: You can store the response and check if you have the response next time `onResume` is called. In that case you redirect the user to Home

Comment: @Eselfar I tried that too, but got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions` exception when tried to close the fragment in onResume(). Should i delay the fragment closing  method?

Comment: @Eselfar the `IllegalStateException` can be avoided using Handler, delaying it by 0ms.

Comment: How did you 'close' your Fragment in `onResume`? Can you please add your code?

Comment: `Handler().postDelayed(object :Runnable{
                override fun run() {
                    fragActivity.onBackPressed()
                }
            }, 0)`